# How to concatenate rows when using with groupby based on a pattern in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an example:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Pretty much, there will be null cells following a value in the Amount Column. I want to concatenate the comment cells of those rows with null cells. I'm not sure how to do this. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what is your sql server version

Comment: Its microsoft SQL Server Studio 18. I tried group_concat or string_concat but those are not recognizable

Comment: Check out this question, it might help you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv

Comment: I tried this method with cross apply using XML path as well, but the problem is sometimes the ID would be the same, so it's just hard to do this. Sorry the original question was off, I edited it

Comment: A bit concerning that there is no explicit order in the rows. You shouldn't rely on the implicit order of rows in the results - that may change.

Comment: @DatNguyen . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You code has no ordering column but the result set seems to depend on ordering.  Hence, you cannot do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  there will be null cells following a value in the Amount Column (as you told in question) you can use ROW_NUMBER() to get unique number in cte and then calculating sum (order by new unique numbers) for every row (will be the same for one Amount).
And at last, using cte in FOR XML PATH().

```
--getting Sum as unique for every sequence (Amount and following values)
with cte AS
(

select Id,Amount,Number,sum(Amount)over(order by Number rows unbounded preceding)SumSeq,comment
from
 (
   select Id,Amount,comment,
   row_number()over(order by Id)Number from Table
 )x

)

 select id,max(Amount),ConcatComments from
  (
    select id,SumSeq,Amount, 
    stuff((select Concat(',',comment) 
    from cte cte1 where cte1.SumSeq=cte2.SumSeq 
    for xml path('')),1,2,'') ConcatComments from cte cte2
 )Z
 group by SumSeq,id,ConcatComments
```

Comment: Dat Nguyen, do you run it?

Comment: thanks so much. It works for the sum sequence. I learn new things from this which is rows unbound now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to concatenate the comments. Something like this:

```
Select ID, MAX(Amount) as Amount, STRING_AGG(Comment, ', ') as Comment
From [YourTable]
Group By ID;
```

Comment: Yes, I tried STRING_AGG as well but for some reasons, the SQL Server Studio 18 could not recognize it

Comment: @DatNguyen There is nothing now that links the comments to the amount. I would not store your data like that if at all possible. For STRING_AGG, you may need to check your database's compatibility level : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I agree that this database is really bad, but it is a pre-existed one. I've been trying to actually implement pattern using a loop but not sure how to do it so far

Comment: You could loop through each row programatically with a cursor if you need to (https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-cursor/).

Comment: Thanks. Let me take a look over there

Answer (score 0):

Your data has no column specifying the ordering, but the results seem to depend on ordering.  If you do have such a column, you can assign a grouping by counting the non-`NULL` values of `amount` for each `id`, and then aggregate.  That would be:

```
select id, grp,
       string_agg(comment, ', ') within group (order by <ordering column>) as comments
from (select t.*, count(amount) over (partition by id order by <ordering column>) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by id, grp;
```

Comment: I tried the string_agg but it was not recognized in my sql server studio 18.